# how to override material ui css using css (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I tried to override the style provided by material ui using css
this is the js file

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import classes from './InputFields.module.css';
export const InputFields = (props) => {
    return (
        <div  className={classes.fields}>
              <TextField 
                    id={props.id}
                    className={classes.field}
                    label={props.label}
                    variant="outlined"
                    type={props.type}
                    onChange={props.onChange}
                    value={props.value}
                    error={props.error}
                   required
                     /> 
        </div>
    )
}
export default InputFields
```

and this is the css file

```
.fields {
   margin: 1rem;
}
.field .MuiInputBase-input{
  height: 3rem;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: just add an "!important" tag at the end of the css command they should work fine as CSS is top down, it will render the latest style from yours.

Answer (score 1):

Add important key word to a css

```
.fields {
    margin: 1rem !imporant;
}
```

Add important key word to a css where you wnat to override it will override the predefined css

Comment: I added in field class but it does not change anything

Comment: oh okay then check this doc to over write  https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#1-specific-variation-for-a-one-time-situation

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use `!important`, at least it be necessary:

You need to apply some changes in your css definition to define a `selector` with a hight level of priority (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In this case you can use `input` type selector, it has more priority than the `class selector`:

```
.fields {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.field input { //--> add input selector
 height: 3rem;
 border: 5px solid green;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: large;
}
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ko3kl

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom TextField component with customized input props.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      height: "3rem",
      border: "5px solid green",
      borderRadius: 3,
      fontSize: "large"
    }
  }),
);

function MyTextField(props: TextFieldProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      InputProps={{ classes } as Partial<OutlinedInputProps>}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

This is based on 'RedditTextField' example on materialui's customized input documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs).